# Integration of payment gateway for Android

Tags: android, paypal

I tried to integrate payment gateway using [PayPal SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK). It works fine. But what I want is, is there any way to avoid the default UI of paypal payment?

I mean paypal SDK opens an UI to input credit card info (card number, expiry date, CCV) to purchase something. I already have those information. So I just want to avoid to input those information again.

Is there any way to pass those information using any method instead of paypals UI?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is it that you already have that information? I think your users would generally be more comfortable inputting their information in a widely known and trusted service (Paypal) than your app.

Comment: Actually this is a private software, will be use in a private network and no one can use it from outside that network. And user have to input their details to use full functionality within this private network.

Surely thanks for your comments. Your point is good.

Comment: Even accepting payment information like this from the user carries inherent risks, not least of which is that you may be liable for leaks (e.g. identity theft) when a user's information gets stolen. In almost all cases, it's better to let a 3rd party payment gateway (like Paypal) handle that part of your app, since it's their **core** business product, and they are (and had better be) experts at it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To directly answer the question, you could use your own UI with Paypals API directly.  See instructions here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/

The issue and why you are seeing it is because the paypal SDK starts a paypal service and that service is what actually processes the payment for you and why you get their UI.  Generally as NasaGeek said it's more comforting to the user to get that known interface to enter their information.  But that's a design choice for you to make...

In researching this I found that using a RESTful API is how Dwolla was doing it in their SDK:
If you look at other payment SDKs on Android, such as Dwolla they do it with a request and response that you handle so you likely wouldn't be stuck with their UI.
https://github.com/therockstorm/dwolla-java-sdk

Comment: It's not necessary that payment method must be paypal. It can be any authorized payment service. Thanks for your advise. I am trying it.